# Typeorm can I not provide entities field in config?

Tags: typeorm

I'm using typeorm nestJs sqlite app
typeorm config is

```
  TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
  type: 'sqlite',
  database: APP_DB_SQLITE_PATH,
  // entities: [UserEntity],
  synchronize: true,
}),
```

also in every module I'm using

```
  imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([UserEntity])],
```

though tables are not creating without entities field in config, why? Can I use forFeature instead of entities ?

Answer (score 1):

The entities property that is part of the object passed to the forRoot method should contain an array of string that indicate where typeorm should find entity definitions in your source code. Mine looks like this:
`"entities": ["dist/**/*.entity.js"]`
see https://sparklytical.gitbook.io/typeorm/connection/connection-options